# User control is not hiding in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, popup, visibility

I created a `UserControl` like `Popup` which is displayed when user clicks on menu item.

If user clicks side that user control should be collapsed.
It works fine for me when user clicks side other than any control.
If I click on datagrid or listbox it is not hiding.

Here is my code:

```
<src:AddNewItemPopUp x:Name="PopUp" Margin="111,47,620,230"  Panel.ZIndex="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

I took a button in click event I set `PopUp` visibility property to true

In my user control I have grid. In the mousedown event of grid I have written following code...

```
private void Grid_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (PopUp.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        PopUp.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

If I click on any control like a `Button`, `DataGrid`, `ListBox` that are placed in `Grid` `Popup` is not collapsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** Set Grid's Background Property, for example `grid.Backgroung=Brushes.Transparent` or in Xaml `Backgroung = "Transparent"`

**Second** Handle `PreviewMouseDown` event instead of `MouseDown` event.

The first one makes the mouse event to fire, when mouse is directly over the grid.

The second one makes the mouse event fire, when mouse is over an UIElement in the grid.

Comment: Working fine..but when i click again on menu item also user control should be collapsed if it is already opened..but first it is collapsing and then again visible..How to fix that?

Comment: Can anyone please tell me the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Visibility="Hidden"
```

that is:

```
private void Grid_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (PopUp.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        PopUp.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

and also see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx